# How I can compare datetime datatype with "12:00:00"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I'm trying to check my transactions in database that occured before midday or "12:00:00". But the compared field datatype is datetime, like "00:00:00". Therefore I want to query the transactions that get time stamp before 12:00:00 in SQL Commands. My database is SQL Server 2005.

Hope everybody can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DatePart` function.

Example:-

```
SELECT *, Convert(VARCHAR, [Date Column], 114)
FROM [Table Name]
WHERE Datepart(hh, [Date Column]) < 12
```